# How data in a d3 scatterplot could be referenced/called outside d3 selection

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 scatterplot and want to know how to get the value of the data appended to one single record (circle) in order to call it later in the code.
Say we have the following data:

```
ID  X   Y
A   1   1
B   2   2
C   3   3
```

How can I get the X value of the record B?

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to show more code, as it depends on how you're attaching the data. But assuming that you have something like

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(myArrayOfDataObjects)
  .enter().append("circle");
```

You can assign an ID or class to the DOM element you create:

```
circle.attr("id", function(d) { return "dataRow" + d.ID; });
```

Now you can use d3, plain JS, or the library of your choice to get a handle on the DOM element later on. D3 attaches its data as a `__data__` property on the DOM element, so you can reference that to get your datum. D3 also provides the `.datum()` method to get this value:

```
var myDataRow = d3.selectAll("#dataRowB").datum();
var xValue = myDataRow.X;
```

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```
var myDataRow = document.getElementById("#dataRowB").__data__;
// etc
```

Comment: Thx, this has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option, in your d3 you can use the jQuery `.data()` function to attach the d3 data directly to the SVG element. Simply run something like `.each(function(d){ $(this).data(d) })`.

You can then access the data anywhere by using `$(selector).data()`, where `selector` points to the DOM element or elements that you're interested in, with something like `'#RecordB'`.

If your data is more complex, (say, `d = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}`), you'd use `$(selector).data()[foo]` to grab whatever data is keyed to 'foo' in the data associated with whatever is pointed at by the selector.